# How to pass vbscript variable into html

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am using vbscript and excels to automate one of my tasks.The below mentioned code automatically draft an email in outlook with an attachement.But still i have to manually enter the 'aa' values and the code '1' value.These values are defined in excel and i want ot fetch it from there.i can get 'name' value from `objFso.GetFileName(objFile.path)`. but i am not sure how to pass these values in the html code.

```
 For Each objFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xls" Then


Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
With MyItem
    .To = "a@abc.com"
    .Subject = ""
    .ReadReceiptRequested = False

    .HTMLBody = "<font size='3' face='Calibri' color='#203B78'>Hi,<BR><BR>Please approve the attached doc for **<b>aa</b>** for code **<b>1</b>.** 



    .Attachments.Add objFolder.Path & "\" & objFso.GetFileName(objFile.path)
End With
MyItem.Display
End if
  Next
Next
```

Please suggest !!!

Comment: try something like: `"<font size='3' face='Calibri' color='#203B78'>Hi,<BR><BR>Please approve the attached doc for <b>" & objFso.GetFileName(objFile.path) & "</b> for code <b>" & VARIABLE_HERE & "</b>." `. Important! empty white spaces between each of `&` are essential to keep them there.

Comment: & objFso.GetFileName(objFile.path) & returns - Timecard Adjustment_Form_Mark_Bunny.xls.. i need to trim it down and only need Mark Bunny..Can you please tell me how to trim this ?

Comment: use combination of `Split` function twice- for `point` and for `underline`. Optionally you could use combination of `Mid`, `InStrRev` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the Excel file

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True  'set to False for production use

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xls")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
```

and insert the values into your mail body:

```
With MyItem
  .HTMLBody = "... approve the attached doc for **<b>" _
    & ws.Cells(1, 1).Value & "</b>** for code **<b>" _
    & ws.Cells(1, 2).Value & "</b>.**"
```

Replace `1, 1` and `1, 2` with the row and column numbers of the cells containing the actual values.

Close the workbook and quit Excel after you're done:

```
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

---

On a different note, `objFile.Path` already has the full path to the file, so you could simply use

```
.Attachments.Add objFile.Path
```

instead of

```
.Attachments.Add objFolder.Path & "\" & objFso.GetFileName(objFile.path)
```

If for some reason you must build the path from a folder and file name, using the [`BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt) method should be preferred over manually building a path by string concatenation:

```
.Attachments.Add objFso.BuildPath(objFolder.Path, objFile.Name)
```

**Edit:** The file name can be transformed like this:

```
name = Replace(Mid(objFso.GetBaseName(objFile.Name), 26), "_", " ")
```

Long version:

```
name = objFso.GetBaseName(objFile.Name) 'get file name without extension
name = Mid(name, 26)             'get part after "Timecard Adjustment_Form_"
name = Replace(name, "_", " ")   'replace underscore with space
```

Comment: Thanks ansgar for detailed info..well, i am getting- Timecard Adjustment_Form_FirstName_LastName.xls but i just want FirstName LastName..

Comment: With or without the underscore between first and last name? With or without extension?